# Bash regex for MD5 or SHA256 not working

Tags: regex, bash

The script with this regex should accept either an MD5 or SHA256 hash as $2, and if it does not match either of those it should alert "ERROR - Hash must be MD5, or SHA256" and exit.

Code :-

```
md5='dd50992572602b8a81e76fa9ca2b4d38'

if ! [[ $md5 =~ ([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64}) ]]; then  
    echo "ERROR - Hash must be MD5, or SHA256"  
    exit 1
fi
```

If variable is less than 32 bytes the ERROR message displays
If variable is 32 bytes the script runs as planned
If variable is between 33 and 63 bytes it moves past the if block even though it shouldn't
If variable is 64 bytes the script runs as planned
If variable is greater than 64 bytes it moves past the if block even though it shouldn't

Comment: best tp add a test case and show your code in action. Also, is there a question? :-) Good luck.

Comment: This could be a locale-dependent issue. Prefer `[[:xdigit:]]` over the ranges.

Comment: Try putting the regex into a variable and then just use `=~ $var` in the condition, then you don't have to do all the escaping, see "Regular Expressions" in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns

Comment: Sorry, don't post on here much! The script should accept either an MD5 hash or a SHA256 hash. If $2 is neither of those formats, the script should alert and exit. I have additional logic after the if block that should execute assuming it doesn't exit.

Comment: Right now it just moves past the if block regardless, so it must not be matching the regex.

Comment: Ideally,  you should show a block of code that reproduces your exact problem, like literally setting a variable to a hash value for which your code fails.

Comment: @chepner: Actually, xdigit is *not* locale-dependent.

Comment: The issue is that anything longer than 32 hex digits will pass your condition. You should use anchor `[[ $2 =~ ^([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64})$ ]]`.

Comment: alvits, that was exactly the fix, thanks! Sorry for the sloppy stackoverflow format guys, TIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the start of line and end of line assertions in your regex:

```
^([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64})$
```

So you code will be like:

```
md5='dd50992572602b8a81e76fa9ca2b4d38'

if ! [[ $md5 =~ ^([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64})$ ]]; then  
    echo "ERROR - Hash must be MD5, or SHA256"  
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: CrafterKolyan thanks for the reply, but I figured it out already thanks to a comment by Alvits. In the sample you posted above you forgot to add the beginning and end of line assertions to the actual code. I tried submitting a change but it’s only two characters and says it needs to be six or more. Still, I will mark this as the correct answer, thanks!

Comment: @MatthewMay Oh, sorry for that. Fixed.